# Kendo Autocomplete doesn't filter DataSource after select in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, listview, kendo-ui, autocomplete, kendo-autocomplete

I have DataSource on page and AutoComplete component and ListView. Both use DataSource. ListView show data from DataSource, and AutoComplete filter data in ListView.

When i type in AutoComplete component, it automatically filter dataSource, and content of ListView is changing because of filtering.

But when AutoComplete show dropDown with filter results and i select some of value, it didn't trigger filter event and content of ListView doesn't change

```
<div class="col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                @(Html.Kendo().DataSource<ProjectQueue>()
                    .Name("projectDataSource")
                    .Ajax(dataSource => dataSource
                       .Read(read => read.Action("ProjectDataSource_Read", "Home"))
                       .ServerOperation(false)
                    )
                )
                @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
                    .Name("autoComplete")
                    .DataTextField("Name")
                    .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
                    .MinLength(2)
                    .DataSource("projectDataSource")
                )

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                @(Html.Kendo().ListView<ProjectQueue>()
                    .Name("projectsListView")
                    .ClientTemplateId("template")
                    .TagName("div")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;" })
                    .Scrollable()
                    .DataSource("projectDataSource")
                    .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(ListViewSelectionMode.Single))
                    .Events(events => events.Change("onChangeProject"))
                )
            </div>
```

How to trigger filtering in DataSource and then in ListView after select event in AutoComplete?

Or can i disable dropdownlist in Aoutocomplete Component and only typing in it?

Answer (score 0):

When you type in the autocomplete the `filtering` event is fired, indeed. However, when you select an item in the popup container with options, the [`select`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/autocomplete/events/select) fires event followed by the [`change`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/autocomplete/events/change) event, when the value of the widget changes.

You can add a select event handler to the AutoComplete, for example, and call the dataSource [`filter`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/filter) method to filter based on the selected item.

```
.Events(ev=>ev.Select("onSelect"))

function onSelect(e){
    projectDataSource.filter({field:"Name", operator: "eq", value: e.dataItem.Name})
}
```

[Here is an example](https://netcorerepl.telerik.com/QIYwvjYV40w4jqyE06)